# How the "magento setup:store-config:set --base-url" command exactly works?

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, base-url, cli

I was thinking that such command was the same as setting the *Base url* from the Magento admin panel, from *Configuration / Store / Web / Base Urls*, but after some try it seems it is not the same.

When I set the *Base url* field from the Magento's Admin Panel, it writes this row inside the `core_config_data` table, with `scope = default`:

```
| scope   | path                   | value                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------|
| default | web/unsecure/base_url  | <base-url-value>      |
```

When I set the `base-url` with the CLI:

```
magento setup:store-config:set --base-url "<new-value>"
```

it deletes the previous row and adds another row, with `scope = websites`

```
| scope    | path                   | value                 |
------------------------------------------------------------|
| websites | web/unsecure/base_url  | <new-value>           |
```

Now, if I go back to the admin panel, I don't see the new value but I see a default value `{{base_url}}` within the *Base url* field.

Finally if I set again the value from the Magento's Admin Panel and I save it, it creates another row inside the table with `scope = default`. And from now I could have two rows with two different `base-url` inside the database (and I'm a bit worried about this).

Since setting the wrong `base-url` could make the website unavailable, I would like to have things clear in mind.

What is the difference between these two methods and what is the proper way to set the `base-url` for a simple Magento e-commerce with only one store?

I can guess it have something to do with multi-store configurations, but I still do not understand how..

Also, is there not a command line to set the `base-url` with `scope = default` (as I was setting it from the admin panel)?

---

The [Magento's documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-store.html) doesn't help me very much:

> --base-url
>
> Base URL to use to access your Magento Admin and storefront in any of the following formats:
>
> - http[s]://[host or ip]/[your Magento install dir]/. Note: The scheme (http:// or https://) and a trailing
>     slash are both required. [your Magento install dir] is the
>     docroot-relative path in which to install the Magento software.
>     Depending on how you set up your web server and virtual hosts, the
>     path might be magento2 or it might be blank. To access Magento on
>     localhost, you can use either http://127.0.0.1/[your Magento install
>     dir]/ or http://127.0.0.1/[your Magento install dir].
> - {{base_url}} which represents a base URL defined by a virtual host setting or by a
>     virtualization environment like Docker. For example, if you set up a
>     virtual host for Magento with the host name magento.example.com, you
>     can install the Magento software with --base-url={{base_url}} and
>     access the Magento Admin with a URL like
>     http://magento.example.com/admin.

Still I don't get where is the difference with the Admin Panel's *Base url* field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can guess it have something to do with multi-store configurations,
>   but I still do not understand how..

It seems that you turn on 'Enable Single-Store Mode' option (Stores / Configuration / General / Single-Store Mode / Enable Single-Store Mode = Yes).

In this case, if you set the Base URL value using Magento CLI, it will be saved with 'websites' scope. If you turn this option off, the Base URL value will be saved with 'default' scope.

Not sure, but it seems that there is no way to set the scope, when you save the config data using Magento CLI.

Comment: Yeah, was that! Thank you. So, better to leave the *Enable Single-Store Mode* option to `false` to avoid problems with `base-url`..