# Setting Store-Specific Options for the non-Default Store via CLI

Tags: magento2, multistore, cli

The Magento CLI application allows you to set store URLs directly, like so:
`bin/magento setup:store-config:set \
--base-url="http://example.dev/" --base-url-secure="https://example.dev/"`

But how can you set the store URL for the second Magento store? I've tried setting the `MAGE_RUN_CODE`, like so, but this only changed the default base store.

`bin/magento setup:store-config:set \
--magento-init-params="MAGE_RUN_CODE=otherstore&MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website" \
--base-url="http://example2.dev/" --base-url-secure="https://example2.dev/"`

Is there something I'm missing? Is it possible to set store config options for stores other than the default store?

Comment: According to this answer, the CLI only updates the "default" scope: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115971/36826

Comment: Of course you can ;)
See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a website or store directly with the param --scope and --scope-code

**php bin/magento config:set --help**

```
Description:
  Change system configuration

Usage:
  config:set [options] [--] <path> <value>

Arguments:
  path                         Configuration path in format section/group/field_name
  value                        Configuration value

Options:
      --scope=SCOPE            Configuration scope (default, website, or store) [default: "default"]
      --scope-code=SCOPE-CODE  Scope code (required only if scope is not 'default')
  -e, --lock-env               Lock value which prevents modification in the Admin (will be saved in app/etc/env.php)
  -c, --lock-config            Lock and share value with other installations, prevents modification in the Admin (will be saved in app/etc/config.php)
  -l, --lock                   Deprecated, use the --lock-env option instead.
  -h, --help                   Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                  Do not output any message
  -V, --version                Display this application version
      --ansi                   Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi                Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction         Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose         Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```